# Loosing Event Handlers on Table elements in jQuery after AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am attaching some `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events on different `tr` elements inside a table. The content inside the table updates via AJAX after a search query.

**The page does not reload, the table content (or its "tr" elements are updated via AJAX without reloading the page.)**

This seems to make the event handlers unresponsive. They stop adding and removing the class I wanted. If I manually put the code inside the browser console and hit enter. The browser again starts adding/removing those classes in response to event handlers.

Can anyone please suggest how can I make sure that all the `tr` elements are still listening to events after AJAX update?

I was using the following code initially:

```
$(".track-table tbody tr").on("mouseenter", function(e) {
  $(this).addClass("currently-active");
});

$(".track-table tbody tr").on("mouseleave", function(e) {
  $(this).removeClass("currently-active");
});
```

After realizing that the `td` elements on which jQuery was listening to these events are gone, I started using Event delegation.

```
$("table").on("mouseenter", ".track-table tbody tr", function(e) {
   $(this).addClass("currently-active");
});

$("table").on("mouseleave", ".track-table tbody tr", function(e) {
   $(this).removeClass("currently-active");
});
```

However, the events are still not captured. I tried running the event handlers inside a `submit` event:

```
$("form").on("submit", function(e) {
   $(".track-table tbody tr").on("mouseenter", function(e) {
     $(this).addClass("currently-active");
   });

   $(".track-table tbody tr").on("mouseleave", function(e) {
     $(this).removeClass("currently-active");
    });
});
```

My question is, how can I keep the event listeners "live" after the AJAX updates the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use event delegation `.on()` but attach it to the `body` instead like :

```
$("body").on("mouseenter", ".track-table tbody tr", function(e) {
    $(this).addClass("currently-active");
});

$("body").on("mouseleave", ".track-table tbody tr", function(e) {
    $(this).removeClass("currently-active");
});
```

Comment: I tried the other answer first because it was posted a few moments earlier. I am guessing this would work as well. However, I am a little confused.  The mouse pointer will always be inside the body. So, when will `mouseleave` be fired?

Comment: I'm afraid that mine was the first posted before the other one (you could check the post time)

Comment: Attaching the event to the body just to ensure that the event will be attached based on an element that will be always loaded... the `track-table` will not work since it will be updated dynamically and lose the event. (Side note attaching the event based on `body` is more efficient than `document`)

Answer (score 0):

You have gone in the right direction yes but what you need to do is use some "outer" element which is always present and yes use delegation. Ex.

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.track-table tbody tr', function(){

});
```

Comment: Thanks Danijel. :) I am a little confused.  The mouse pointer will always be inside the document. So, when will `mouseleave` be fired?

Comment: It's not about the event, it's about the element `.track-table tbody tr`. This is what is being replaced by ajax and is dynamic so in order to attach another listener on this new dynamic element, you should use some "outer" element which is loaded on page load. `document` or `body` are your best bets. So when ajax call is done, you attach events again on this new elements using the syntax above.